# How to add row index on a group of 2 ordered columns such that the row index restarts for each group, for a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, group-by, row-number

I have a PySpark dataframe-

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", 10),
    ("u1", 20),
    ("u2", 10),
    ("u2", 10),
    ("u2", 30),
    ],
    ['user_id', 'var1'])

print(df1.printSchema())
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

It looks like-

```
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- var1: long (nullable = true)

None
+-------+----+
|user_id|var1|
+-------+----+
|u1     |10  |
|u1     |20  |
|u2     |10  |
|u2     |10  |
|u2     |30  |
+-------+----+
```

I want to give row index in such a way that the indexing restarts for each group on user_id(sorted in ascending order) and var1(sorted in descending order).

The desired output should look like-

```
+-------+----+-----+
|user_id|var1|order|
+-------+----+-----+
|u1     |10  |    1|
|u1     |20  |    2|
|u2     |10  |    1|
|u2     |10  |    2|
|u2     |30  |    3|
+-------+----+-----+
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a row number operation:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df1.withColumn(
    'order', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('var1'))
)

df2.show()
+-------+----+-----+
|user_id|var1|order|
+-------+----+-----+
|     u1|  10|    1|
|     u1|  20|    2|
|     u2|  10|    1|
|     u2|  10|    2|
|     u2|  30|    3|
+-------+----+-----+
```